# Are there are any good solutions for comment alignment?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, rider

I like aligning the code like this

```cs
test.memberName = "dough"; // Name of the Member field.
test.age = 34; // Name of the Member field.
```

To this:

```cs
test.memberName = "dough";  // Name of the Member field.
test.age = 34;              // Name of the Member field.
```

To tap my <kbd>Tab</kbd> key with <kbd>Space</kbd>. This is kind of sucks. Are there any plugins or tools for this pretty simple task?

I'm working in JetBrains IDEs and VSCode.

Comment: there are some **align** extensions, search the marketplace

Comment: don't ask for solutions for two IDEs in one question post. Split it into two question posts. make sure to search for whether the question has been asked for each one before asking.

Comment: Check the **Code Style** in your JetBrains IDE -- code formatters for some languages support this (will be used on Code Reformat action). I know that PhpStorm has it for PHP for example (may depend on a specific language construct though). Other than that: check the Plugins screen, search for `align`, e.g. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?search=align